# XSendEvent does not change modifier key state

Tags: c++, c, x11, keyboard-events, xlib

I'm trying to send key events by creating a XKeyEvent and sending it using XSendEvent (inspired by [this](http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html) post). The XKeyEvents are prepared as follows:

```
XKeyEvent createKeyEvent(Display *display, Window win, Window winRoot, _Bool press, int keycode, int modifiers) {
    XKeyEvent event;

    event.display     = display;
    event.window      = win;
    event.root        = winRoot;
    event.subwindow   = None;
    event.time        = CurrentTime;
    event.x           = 1;
    event.y           = 1;
    event.x_root      = 1;
    event.y_root      = 1;
    event.same_screen = True;
    event.keycode     = keycode;
    event.state       = modifiers;

    if (press) {
        event.type = KeyPress;
    } else {
        event.type = KeyRelease;
    }

    return event;
}
```

Then they are sent with `XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, 1, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);`

The key events are sent and the target program receives them (letters are entered, arrow keys work etc.). However, problems arise with modifier keys. Let's say the program sends a key-down event for the opt/alt key. In this scenario, the text in the menu bar is underlined until a key-up event is sent (indicating that the X-server has received and processed the key-down event).

However, when retrieving the the current state of the modifier keys, the modifier keys do not appear to be pressed at all. When calling `XQueryPointer(self->display, winFocus, &root_return, &child_return, &root_x_return, &root_y_return, &win_x_return, &win_y_return, &keyboard_state_mask);`, the keyboard_state_mask is 0. Checking the keyboard with `xev` gives the same result. Physically pressing the modifier keys does change the state mask, both in `xev` and in my code.

How do I properly change the current modifier-key state?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me but, are you expecting the X11 servers view of the keyboard modifiers state to be affected by the events you send?

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using the method `int XTestFakeButtonEvent(display, button, is_press, delay)` from the library `<X11/extensions/XTest.h>`. For some reason, this causes the keyboard modifier state to change when sending a modifier key (as I wanted), while the above-mentioned method does not.

Answer (score 0):

From xsendevent man pages:

"The contents of the event are otherwise unaltered and unchecked by the X server except except to force send_event to True in the forwarded event and to set the serial number in the event correctly."

I assume that you copied createKeyEvent() from the following place: http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html

And if you also copied the way this function is called:

createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, false, KEYCODE, 0);

then it makes sense that "modifier" is not set to anything, as the last argument is "0". According to documentation you need to set the modifier state yourself.

I did not verify this information. If it does not work as documented, that it might be a documentation bug or a bug in X server's implementation.